# How do you append two bytes to an int

Tags: java, integer, append, byte

I'm trying to append two bytes that have hex values and store them into an integer. So obviously everything will be unsigned values.
I'll provide an example since that is much easier to see.

two bytes
0x20  0x07

Integer
Edit: Oops I made a huge mistake here. Sorry for all the confusion.
I want integer to store 2007 not 0x2007. I'm really sorry about that.

Is there way to do this without converting the byte to String and append and switch to int?
or is converting to String is the only way?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Could you tell us what the value of integer would be when you have something like `two bytes 0x2F 0x3F`?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion. I've edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
byte b1 = (byte) 0x90;
byte b2 = (byte) 0xF7;

int i = ((b1 & 0xFF) << 8) | (b2 & 0xFF);
```

However if you are using `DataInputStream` or `ByteBuffers` you usually don't need to do this.  Just use `getShort` in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just shift b1 by 8 bits and add it to b2:

```
byte b1 = 0x20;
byte b2 = 0x07;

int i1 = (b1 << 8) + b2; // gives 0x2007

// alternatively
int sameInt = b1 * 256 + b2; // gives 0x2007
```

Comment: More elegant woudl be: (b1 <<8) | b2

Comment: This assumes both values are between 0 and 127.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It assumes both byte values are between 0 and 255 (i.e., 0x00 and 0xFF), which will always be the case since they're bytes. E.g., 0xFF*256 + 0xFF = 0xFFFF.

Comment: @aleph_null `bytes` in Java are between -128 and 127 as its signed. You can't have unsigned bytes as such in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: oops... java sign extends the byte when promoting it to an int. Thanks for the correction.